# PHP OOP - how to call the overriding method of the child class

Tags: php, oop

Consider class A and B as follows:

```
Class A {

   public function A1 (){
      $this->A2();
   }

   public function A2 (){}

}

Class B extends A {

  public function A2 () {} // overriding A2

}


$instance= new B ();
$instance -> A1();  // Calling A1 of class B which calls the parent class A1 actually
```

As you can see Class B overrides function A2.
A2 is called from class A method A1

The problem is that it calls the A2 in class A and not the overriding A2 in class B.

How can I make sure that if I override a method, the overriding method will be invoked even if it is called from a parent class (A) method (when the actual object is an instance of the overriding (B) class.

Comment: I was not able to [reproduce the problem](https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/e74c62a00af63b25b0e1)

Comment: It's not really clear, what you want to achive. Everything is fine with this. You instantinate an object from class `B`. Calling on this the `A1` (what wasn't overrided anywhere), it calling `A`s `A1` method. Fine. Then calling `$this` what is actally `B`. And `B` is overwrited the method `A2` of  `A`

Comment: It *will* call `B::A2`. If that's not what you get, provide an example that clearly demonstrates the problem. This sample here does not demonstrate any problem.

Comment: Do you want the `$this->A2()` to execute `A::A2` function? If yes, then use: `self::A2();`

Comment: Usually you don't use A's A2 when your object is of type B. The other way round is very common, when you need to call the parent's method: `parent::A2` (in B).

Comment: Thanks everybody! Looks like the code does work as expected so my question is not valid. The actual code in which I saw the problem is complex and it seems to be working differently there than in the examples here. I will try to find the difference. Thank you good people !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am knowing this is not an answer, but i want to make clear, what OP asking, and want to formatting the code.

```
Class A {

    public function A1() {
        echo "Class A, method A1 <br />";
        $this->A2();
    }

    public function A2() {
        echo "Class A, method A2 <br />";
    }

}

Class B extends A {

    public function A2() {
        echo "Class B, method A2 <br />";
    }

    // overriding A2
}

$instance = new B ();
$instance->A1();
```

Output of this is:

```
Class A, method A1
Class B, method A2
```

**To OP**: What is your desired output?

Comment: The examples here by lolka_bolka  kojiro  show that the code actually work as expected and that my question is not valid. Sorry and thank you ! You've helped a lot.